# Using new to allocate memory for unsigned char array fails

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I'm trying to load a tga file in c++ code that I got from google searching, but the part that allocates memory fails. The beginning of my "LoadTarga" method includes these variables:

```
int imageSize;
unsigned char* targaImage;
```

Later on in the method the imageSize variable gets set to 262144 and I use that number to set the size of the array:

```
// Calculate the size of the 32 bit image data.
    imageSize = width * height * 4;
// Allocate memory for the targa image data.
    targaImage = new unsigned char[imageSize];
    if (!targaImage)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, L"LoadTarga - failed to allocate memory for the targa image data", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
```

The problem is that the body of the if statement executes and I have no idea why the memory allocation failed. As far as I know it should work - I know the code compiles and runs up to this point and I haven't seen anything yet in google that would show a proper alternative.

**What should I change in my code to make it allocate memory correctly?**

**Important Update:**

Rob L's comments and suggestions were very useful (though I didn't try _heapchk since I solved the issue before I tried using it)

Trying each of fritzone's ideas meant the program ran past the "if (!targaImage)" point without trouble. The code that sets "targaImage and the if statement checks if memory was allocated correctly has been replaced with this:

```
try
{
    targaImage = new unsigned char[imageSize];
}
catch (std::bad_alloc& ba)
{
    std::cerr << "bad_alloc caught: " << ba.what() << '\n';
    return false;
}
```

However I got a new problem with the very next bit of code:

```
count = (unsigned int)fread(targaImage, 1, imageSize, filePtr);
if (count != imageSize)
{
    MessageBox(hwnd, L"LoadTarga - failed to read in the targa image data", L"Error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}
```

Count was giving me a value of "250394" which is different to imageSize's value of "262144". I couldn't figure out why this was and doing a bit of searching (though I must admit, not much searching) on how "fread" works didn't yield info.

I decided to cancel my search and try the answer code on the tutorial site here http://www.rastertek.com/dx11s2tut05.html (scroll to the bottom of the page where it says "Source Code and Data Files" and download the zip. However creating a new project, putting in the source files and image file didn't work as I got a new error. At this point I thought maybe the way I converted the image file from to tga might have been incorrect.

So rather than spend a whole lot of time debugging the answer code I put the image file from the answer into my own project. I noted that the size of mine was MUCH smaller than the answer (245KB compared to 1025 KB) )so maybe if I use the answer code's image my code would run fine. Turns out I was right! Now the image is stretched sideways for some reason but my original query appears to have been solved.

Thanks Rob L and fritzone for your help!

Comment: Memory allocation have all rights to fail. Maybe you're asking for too much contiguous memory. What's the value of `imageSize`?

Comment: You must be using a really old compiler, or a weird compatibility switch. Plain `new` never returns null in standard C++, so the compiler would be justified in completely removing your if-statement.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2013 express to compile the code, should I get a newer version?

Comment: You don't need VS 2015, VS 2013 is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **NOT** using the form of `new` which returns a *null pointer* in case of error, so it makes no sense for checking the return value. Instead you should be aware of catching a `std::bad_alloc`. The *null pointer* returning `new` for you has the syntax: `new (std::nothrow) unsigned char[imageSize];`

Please see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in your sample looks wrong.  It is pretty unlikely that a modern Windows system will run out of memory allocating 256k just once. Perhaps your allocator is being called in a loop and allocating more than you think, or the value of imagesize is wrong.  Look in the debugger.

Another possibility is that your heap is corrupt.  Calling _heapchk() can help diagnose that.

Comment: Had a look for any loops and the value of image size in the debugger but there be no loops and the values for width, height and imageSize all look good. I'll look into heap check and fritzone's throwing exceptions idea and see what they turn up. Thanks for your help btw :)

Comment: Fritzone is definitely correct that you should never get null with "normal" compiler settings.  Really sounds like corruption somewhere.  You might want to go to an assembler window and trace the call. Even if you don't read assembler well, you can often figure out what is going on.

Comment: I'll give that a try too then - I've never heard of assembler windows till now so I'll need to read up on them. Always good to have more ways to debug things :)

Comment: I'm going to update the original post with my findings, both you and fritzone provided very useful debugging tools so I couldn't decide who to mark as the correct answerer. I didn't get around to trying _heapchk() as I fixed the problem (well the program runs and displays a triangle with a texture on it anyway which is good) so my memory issues are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "memory peak working set" in windows tasks manager and ensure how much memory you are really trying to allocate.